# remove method throws error in List interface iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to use remove method but I am getting messed up as I keep getting error for this:

```
 List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
      list1.add("Apple");
      list1.add("Bus");
      list1.add("Cat");
      list1.add("Dog");
      String ne = list1.listIterator().next();
System.out.println(ne);
list1.listIterator().remove();
```

the remove statement throws an error?? can anyone tell me why??
same thing when I just use iterator in place of listIterator?

Comment: Issue is that you are getting a new ListIterator object when you do `list1.listIterator()` a second time. And a `.remove()` would only work after a `.next()`or a `.previous()` call. Either re-use the first `ListIterator` by assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct in that you are allowed to call `ListIterator#remove()` once for each time `next()` is called (see [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove())).  However, in your code you are actually calling `remove()` on a *new* list iterator, not the one you used before it.  Try the following code and hopefully it will be clear what you did wrong:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("Apple");
list1.add("Bus");
list1.add("Cat");
list1.add("Dog");
// retain a reference to the same list iterator
ListIterator<String> list1itr = list1.listIterator();
String ne = list1itr.next();
System.out.println(ne);
list1itr.remove();
```

## Demo

Comment: tried that but now I am getting cannot find symbol for listIterator and just to be sure I imported it as well!!

Comment: @user7703770 I think it should already be available, if not, `ListIterator` is part of the `java.util` package.

Comment: thats why I am confused becasue it says
ava:12: error: cannot find symbol
      ListIterator<String> list1itr = list1.listIterator();

do we have to do new or something on using it for first time??

Comment: @user7703770 Sorry I had a typo in there, the update should run with no issue, check the demo.